# How to automate , to open a RSAToken application and simulate keystroke and to press Enter using AutoHotKey

Tags: automation, autohotkey

I want to automate the following

1)Open the RSAToken Application

2)Simulate keystrokes to enter the PIN (say for eg : 223344 in that application)

3)Also to simulate the Enter keystroke upon entering the PIN

4)Copying passcode generated

i tried coding it by referring couple of articles but it was not working.

Following is the code

```
Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Software Token\SecurID.exe"
;; 2222 is the PIN Code
Send, 2222
Sleep, 100
Send, {ENTER}
Sleep, 100
Send, ^c
Sleep, 100
```

Could anyone tell me , what am i missing ?

Comment: Try using WinWait, WinActivate and WinWaitActive before sending commands to the window.

Comment: In addition to user3419297's suggestion, I found that using the run command in [expression mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm#-expression) has better results.  Like so: `run, % "C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Software Token\SecurID.exe"`

Comment: Say what is not working, please!!  Does the app even open up in the first place?  Is the focus on a text box when you open it?  If so, did you try other send modes?  Or put PIN in clipboard and paste it to field?  Are the numbers being entered into the field, but just not being sent when you hit enter?  Details will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to wait for the application to start after running it. As I don't have the application, I can only suggest something like this:

```
WinWaitActive ahk_exe SecurID.exe
```

Then you need to copy the resulting code.

`Ctrl+C` only works if the code is selected, which it probably isn't. So `Send ^c` won't work.

Again, I don't have the application, but if it looks like this:

[image: dialog]
<sub>(source: [rsa.com](https://community.rsa.com/resources/statics/103845/windows-desktop-token-502.png?a=1490806539629))</sub>

you need to move the keyboard focus to the Copy button and push it using the keyboard. That can probably be done either by

```
Send {Tab}{Enter}
```

or simply

```
Send {Enter}
```

if the button is already the default button.

In total, we have something like this:

```
Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Software Token\SecurID.exe"

; Wait a while for the window to appear and become active.
timeoutSeconds:= 2
WinWaitActive ahk_exe SecurID.exe,, %timeoutSeconds% 

if not ErrorLevel {
    ; The window is now active.

    ;; 2222 is the PIN Code
    Send, 2222   ; Type the PIN code.
    Sleep, 100
    Send, {ENTER}  ; Send the PIN code.
    Sleep, 200   ; Wait for the program to generate the passcode.
    Send {Tab}   ; Move focus to the Copy button; this might not be needed.
    Send {Enter}  ; Press the Copy button.
    Sleep, 100  ; Wait for the copy to happen; often unnecessary.
} else
    MsgBox The window did not appear within %timeoutSeconds% seconds.
```

The general algorithm for writing a script like this is to first do the task manually using the keyboard only. When you can make that work, make a script that presses the same keys as you pressed manually.

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks for fixing the image!